# Java : String a = Integer.toString(1); creates how many objects?

Tags: java, string

I have seen statements that says :

```
String a = new String("1");
```

creates 2 objects, both on heap, one is referenced by a, one is ref-ed from String literal pool

**but, how about:**

```
String a = Integer.toString(1);
```

will it create 2 objects or 1? 
I think it creates 2, am I correct?

Comment: It'll probably create a couple more in the internal implementation of `Integer.toString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the source of [`Integer#toString(int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%29). It returns a new String object.

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(0, size, buf);
}
```

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer so toStirng impl would create 2 objects one char[] and new String() in the return.I was answering to `String a = Integer.toString(1);` where Integer#toString(1) would create a new string object rather than using a cached string.

Answer (score 3):

It will create zero objects because the JVM will optimize it away ;-)

In other words: I believe that the answer to that question is more related to the underlying virtual machine than to Java.

Answer (score 2):

It'll create two: one `char[]` in the implementation of `Integer.toString`, and then the `String` it converts that to.

Answer (score 1):

The internal implementation of the method can create as many as it wants, as long as it satisfies the public contract of the method.

That said, looking at the current implementation, the only additional object (besides the String whose reference is returned) is:

```
    char[] buf = new char[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

[In the OpenJdk implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%29), a `char` array is created and then a String is created from that.

Answer (score 0):

The **first** time:

```
String a = new String("1");
```

is executed it will create at least two if not more objects. Clearly it will create a `String`, which will probably contain a `private` `char[]`. There will also be a new entry in the `intern` map which may consist of more than one object. So - in summary - at least two and maybe four or even more.

From then on - however, it should only create **one** object, the `String`. The `char[]` will be shared from the intern map.

Each time you execute

```
String a = Integer.toString(1);
```

you will create at least one object. Obviously the `String` and probably a new `char[]` and probably maybe nothing else. You may not even create the `char[]` if it uses the `intern`ed version of "1" created above.

In general - it depends on the JVM.

Comment: String literals are constructed at link time, last i checked.  That is, `"1"` already exists, as a String, before the code even runs.

Answer (score 0):

Case one creates *three* objects (char[], String constant and new String), not two. Case two create *two* objects (char[] and new String). Checked the JRE 1.7.0_21 sources, other JRE's may implement it differently.

Comment: The String literal is added to the pool when the class containing it is loaded; neither the constructor nor the caller will create it for the call.  And since Strings are immutable, there's nothing preventing `String(String other)` from simply copying `other`'s fields, including the reference to its underlying char array.  In fact, that's exactly what it does, unless `other`'s char array has unused space in it -- which should not be the case for a String literal.

Comment: Thats exactly what I said, isn't it? The TC asked about the *Statement*, he does not specify if he wants to count the constant pool allocation or not (I assumed he wants to, since he assumed two objects for the first case). A String literal is allocated as a normal char[] and String in the constant pool, so that makes two objects, or doesn't it?

Comment: Depends on whether the question was about having the statement in one's code, or running it, or both.  Having it creates at least two (the char[] and the String) when the class is loaded (unless `"1"` already exists elsewhere in the code), and running it creates one more.